# Limit which classes can be stored in a specific Realm

Tags: ios, realm

When I try to add object classes to my migrations i.e. `config.objectClasses = @"[ImageEntity.class]` to migrations the following exception is thrown:

```
if (!objectSchema) {
    @throw RLMException(@"Object type '%@' is not persisted in the Realm. "
                         @"If using a custom `objectClasses` / `obejctTypes` array in your configuration, "
                         @"add `%@` to the list of `objectClasses` / `objectTypes`.",
                         className, className);
}
```

Did I add the class to the class list (config.objectClasses) in the **wrong way**? Or is the exception **not descriptive enough**? Could it be that **something else** is wrong?

Most of my models look like this:

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

@interface ImageEntity : RLMObject

@property NSString *verticalLarge;
@property NSString *horizontalLarge;

@end

// This protocol enables typed collections. i.e.:
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(ImageEntity)
```

**The realm manual states the following:**

***Class Subsets***
In some scenarios you may wish to limit which classes can be stored in a specific Realm. For example, if you have two teams working on different components of your application which both use Realm internally, you may not want to have to coordinate migrations between them. You can do this by setting the objectClasses property of your RLMRealmConfiguration:

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
config.objectClasses = @[MyClass.class, MyOtherClass.class];
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config];
```

**Conditions** (Where it happens):

1. First Run - Realms are created (clean build i.e. no previous realms are available).
2. Migrations are done incl. objectClasses config.
   I can see the realms are created in the user directory.
3. Happens at

   ```
       [customRealm beginWriteTransaction];
       [customEntity createOrUpdateInRealm:customRealm withJSONArray:responseObject];
       [customRealm commitWriteTransaction];
   ```

Ps. the same doesn't happen without the objectClasses config.

Somehow the specific realm (where the exception occurs) inherits object classes from the default realm and the other realms don't inherit object classes (like it should work when using config.objectClasses).

Comment: Would you mind providing a bit more info to make it possible to help you? Where does exception happen in your code? Instantiation Realm? Or in the migration block?

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi Thanks for answering. I've edited my question with the additional info. But I'm already narrowing it down to one specific realm, because I can see something is wrong with it when comparing all realms in the realm browser.

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi I verified the realm files in the realm browser, but somehow the specific realm (where the exception occurs) inherits object classes from the default realm and the other realms don't inherit object classes (like it should work when using config.objectClasses).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? If you believe to have found a bug in Realm, please report it by filing an issue following the guidelines in https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#filing-issues

Comment: @jpsim - no not yet, just not using objectClasses till I have time to research a bit more, maybe I did something wrong for this specific realm config.. because other realm files did work fine with objectClasses.